# Persistent password login screen for Windows, CE 5.0

Tags: security, passwords, reboot, login-screen, windows-ce

I'm fairly new to the window CE 5.0 platform. I'm using an MC9090. I'm able to successfully set a password by going into control panel. The password screen is good up until the device has its battery removed or has a warm or cold boot performed on it. then password is wiped which makes the whole idea behind a password log on pointless. How can I make the password persistent after a reboot warm boot, cold boot and battery removal?